# How do I get the details of an install transaction using apt in Ubuntu 23.04 lunar lobster

Tags: apt

I have an assembled PC with multi-boot OS. Fedora 38 and Ubuntu 23.04 equally share an 1 TiB disk.

I use `sudo --login dnf --noplugins history info <transaction_id>` to get the **comprehensive** details of a transaction ( install , remove , and/or update ) of a package on **dnf** based systems

How can I get a similar information in an **apt** based system ?

Please review and assist!

Comment: `apt` doesn't have transactions like dnf/yum. You'll have to check the logs (`/var/log/apt/*`)